# Custom admin interface in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, static-files, django-staticfiles, django-1.4

Django's documentation provides an easy way of installing `admin` app.
It assumes the structure of files as follows:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
          settings.py #adding `admin` under `INSTALLED_APPS`
          __init__.py
          urls.py #adding urls
          wsgi.py
    myapp/
    __init__.py
    admin.py #creating this file
    models.py
    views.py
```

My question is how to get the `admin` interface to work if my structure is as follows:

```
mysite/
      manage.py
      settings.py
      __init__.py
      urls.py
      myapp/
          __init__.py
          forms.py
          models.py
          views.py
```

What will be the various changes that I will have to incorporate to get the `admin` interface working. [my other apps are working].
I have read and read the documentation several times.
I'm using `Django` `1.4`.

**EDIT#1**

I'm getting this error on running `localhost:8000/admin/`:

```
error at /admin/
unknown specifier: ?P[
```

[Whole error here](http://dpaste.com/852582/).

My `urls.py` file has the lines [as in the docs]:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/(.*)', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My `admin.py` file in the `myapp` folder has the code:

```
import models
from django.contrib import admin

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(models.Article, PostAdmin)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What's the problem? There really should be no issue

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: The whole error is on : http://dpaste.com/852582/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you're supposed to include the admin urls:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf) shows this.

The error that you're getting is coming straight from the `re` python module, complaining about this part of a url:

```
?P[
```

The URLs you've posted in your comment beneath show this:

```
url(r'^(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$', 'myapp.views.getPost')
```

Try changing that url by giving the match group a name:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$', 'myapp.views.getPost')
```

And in your `getPost` view, include a `slug` argument.

Comment: Still the same error. My complete `urls.py` file is:
`from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.login_user'),

 url(r'^(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$', 'myapp.views.getPost'),
 (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
`

Comment: @xan, take a look at my update. I think your other URL is the problem. There's a regex containing `?P[` which is failing.